# convert text box string to label in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rendering, renderpartial

i have a check box and a text box.
On selection of the check box, the string in the text box must be returned in the form of  a label.
I am new to MVC. please provide some guidelines and links.

Html:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" name="comBox" />
<input type ="text" id="comment" />
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controllers/HomeController',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'html'

    }).success(function (result) {    
        $('#comm1').html(result);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail and perhaps some code.

Comment: I am accepting string from text box and want to convert it to label, so passing it to Controller. What action has to be taken here?